# What is the best way to parse a Pandas dataframe from a CSV with datapoints in columns?

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a CSV file containing some time-series data, with time spread out over columns rather than rows:

```
Town,2021-01-01,2021-01-02,2021-01-03
Abingdon,4.1,7.2,6.3
```

There are just two rows in the file, the first having the dates, and the second having the values. Each row has N+1 columns.

I would like to get this into a dataframe with two columns and N rows, with each date-value datapoint in a row. I am happy to discard the metadata in the first column of the CSV file.

What is the best way to do this?

What i have so far is:

```
values_t = pd.read_csv('values.csv', index_col=0, header=None)
values = values_t.T
values.columns = ('date', 'value')
```

Which mostly works - except that the values are strings!

```
type(values.loc['2021-01-01']['value']) == str # True!
```

My tentative guess is that the values are strings because the type of the column in the first dataframe, parsed directly from the CSV, was set by the contents of the first row. Is there a way to avoid this coercion?

Comment: I would do the same as you and just parse the `values` to the desired types.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, and would just explicitly convert the dates and floats in a subsequent step. That said `df = pd.read_csv('values.csv', index_col=0, header=0).T` will read them in as floats (assuming they are all valid floats...) indexed by date-like strings. Also, your column index will be named "Town".